# Finding Missing Letters

Tags: python, ascii, frequency

I'm currently trying to create a function that counts the frequency of characters in in a string. I need to store it in a dictionary in ASCII code. From this dictionary I need to calculate which letters do not appear in the string.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPbRv.png)

```
import string
result=string.ascii_uppercase
print(result)
```

```
string_1 = 'WSXFGTYUJNMKLOIUYGFDXCVBHJKLMNBVFDEW'
frequencies = {}
```

```
for char in string_1:
    if char in frequencies:
        frequencies[char] +=1
    else:
        frequencies[char]=1
print("per char frequenct in '{}'is :\n{}".format(string_1, str(frequencies)))
```

```
list(string_1.encode('ascii'))
```

```
alphabet=set(ascii_uppercase)
```

```
def find_missing_letter(string_1)
    return alphabet - (string_1)
Print(find_missing_letter(string_1))
```

I've managed most of it just cant get it to identify which letters are not present in the string.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular ask a question at all. 
What  have you tried so far? Where did you struggle? Which programming language do you use at all? Show us your code and ask a specific question if you want to get help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. Just transform the string to a set first, then subtract the letters from the letters of the alphabet.

```py
def find_missing_letter(string_1):
    return set(string.ascii_uppercase) -  set(string_1)

result = find_missing_letter(string_1)
print(result) # {'A', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'Z'}
print(f'Number of missing letters: {len(result)}')
```

Comment: is there an easy way to then count the missing letters?

Comment: You can use `len()` to get the size of the set that is returned by the function. I edited the answer.